# How to use Get function as object

Tags: php, laravel

Im making a login page , so i need to compare the passoword form DB and the on form form , whats wrong with my code , it says Trying to get property of non-object

Using laravel

```
public function index()
{
    // $mahasiswa =  DB::table('mahasiswa')-> get();
    return view('index');
}

public function cek(Request $request)
{
    $user = DB::table('mahasiswa')->where('npm', $request->npm)->first();

    if ($user->Password == $request->password) {
        redirect('welcome');
    } else {
        return ('eror');
    }
}
```

I expect its all right to write like that

Comment: and if you dd($user); you get some result?

Comment: On what line are you getting this error?

Comment: where should i put dd to check ?

Comment: i got error in line 17

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use

```
Auth::attempt
```

to check user credentials  and this is the correct way to do what you want
or
use this code

```
if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    // true...
}
```

and the error Trying to get property of non-object 
as you write in your code

```
 if($user->Password == $request->password){
        redirect('welcome');
    }
```

the problem with Password you write p as a capital not small
I hope my answer help you!

Comment: i ve tried hash but still got error Trying to get property of non-object when it tried to get password from $user , any solution ?

Comment: Sir ,you cannot write code as you think not a good way 
the best way is 
    if(Auth::attempt(['npm'=>$request->npm,'password'=>$request->password])){
        redirect('welcome');
    }
    else{
        return('eror');
    }

Comment: plz,if you find this helpful and useful,accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

try this, if the error persist, check your database password field if its getting the field. `$user->password;`

```
public function index()
    {
        // $mahasiswa =  DB::table('mahasiswa')-> get();
        return view('index');
    }

    public function cek(Request $request)
    {
        $user = DB::table('mahasiswa')->where('npm', $request->input('npm'))->first();

        if ($user->Password == $request->input('password')) {
            redirect('welcome');
        } else {
            return ('erorr');
        }
    }
```